# Standalone package installation

Tags: input, standalone

I want to include a table in a tex file and I get this error: ! LaTeX Error: File `standalone.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.

I have tries to install the standalone fille from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone   but I can't install it.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{exam}
    \usepackage[french,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%pour inclure documents 
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
    \usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{dcolumn}
    \usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
....
\input {pi_tableau_diagnosis_adult}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you install it with your package manager?

Comment: you could get standalone from ctan (or better if using texlive or miktex) from the package manager, but why do you need standalone to input a table??

Comment: Bernard and David : I tried to find the package manager with Miktex but I didn't find it. I dont know why I get that error. It says standalone.sty not found. How cand I find it ?, Mico how do you do that (load it via documentclass?

Comment: @Mico It is also a package. When you include the file in your main document, you load it as a package. When you compile it on its own, you load it as the document class.

Comment: You definitely should use MiKTeX's manager. Or set it up to install missing files on-the-fly.

Comment: When I compile I get a windows saing: that the tex/latex/standalone/standalone.sty  is missing. And the It istall it from the directory, but apparently It didn't find it

Comment: I don't use miktex so can't help with the details but searching for miktex package manager here should show lots of examples. But why do you need standalone, what is in `pi_tableau_diagnosis_adult.tex` / why can you not just `\input` it normally/

Comment: Hi everybody. I used the Miktex package manager to install standalone package and also other 3 packages (related to standalone), it is not difficult  and now it works !!!!! Thank you all !!!! ;-)

Comment: How can I put that the question was answered ?

Comment: yes but this question was specifically about standalone and we finally found that using the package manager we can do it.